# SL(2,Q) transformation of Jacobi Theta functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know how the theta function $\theta_{1}(z;\tau)$ transforms under the shift $\tau \rightarrow  \tau + \frac{m}{n}$, with $ m,n$ integer numbers:

$\theta_{1}(z;\tau + \frac{m}{n})=......$

Do you know the answer or some book where this kind of transformation relations are discussed? Thank you !!!

Comment: There is no simpler expression for the $\tau$ shift in general as far as I know. It would be very unusual. That goes for shifting $z$ as well.